# Open Source Dynamic form builder for HTML forms?

Tags: html, forms, jotform

I am looking for an Open Source Dynamic form builder something like http://www.jotform.me/ but free and Open Source and the End form must be in HTML no XHTML nothing else. Is their anything available ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit: Thanks [@Stefan Steiger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/155077/stefan-steiger)
Better try: [alpacajs.org](http://www.alpacajs.org/) which you can find on github: [github.com/gitana/alpaca](https://github.com/gitana/alpaca)

Have you tried FormTools?
 https://formtools.org/ try this link might be helpful.

Comment: Better try: http://www.alpacajs.org/ which you can find on github: https://github.com/gitana/alpaca